# Share cookies accoss localhost ports

Tags: go

I would like to add a cookie to my client sharing different port (I develop a backend on port A and a front app on port B, both running on localhost).

So I made two minimal server to test, presenting a simple Session link :

```golang
func newClient() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(r.Host)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `
            <a href="http://localhost:5000/session">Session</a>
         `)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", mux)
}

func newServer() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/session", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        cookie := http.Cookie{
            Name:     "Foo",
            Value:    "Bar",
            HttpOnly: true,
        }
        r.AddCookie(&cookie)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:5000", mux)
}
```

Unfortunately, the cookie is not set on the client when I click on the session ref.

Can anyone explain to me why ? It seems that both are running on same domain (localhost).

Comment: Cookies are identified via (Host,Path,Name). You set your cookie with an implicite path of /session but try to read it from path /. This doesn't work. Add `Path: "/",` to your cookie. (Ports have no role in cookies.)

Comment: ty for explanation. Host there is considered different. host is localhost:4000 for first, localhost:5000 for second. Editing path does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question**

As pointed out by others; host does not matter in that scenario. However, I was simply missing the [SetCookie](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#SetCookie) to set writer cookie :

```
r.AddCookie(&cookie)
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```